# Changing my stored procedure to Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a question regarding how to convert the following to linq. I've been trying to get my head around ASP.NET MVC, and one of the biggest hurdles for me is Linq.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectAvailableCoops]
    @startDate DATETIME, @endDate DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT ID, coopName, coopCPN
    FROM tbl_Coops
    WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT coopID
                     FROM tbl_bookings 
                     WHERE (startDate <= @startDate AND endDate >= @startDate)
                        OR (startDate < @endDate AND endDate >= @endDate)
                        OR (@startDate <= startDate AND @endDate >= endDate)
                    )
END
GO
```

If it helps, at the moment I have the following in my action result.

```
BookingsListVM bookinglist = new BookingsListVM();
//bookinglist.Customers = db.Customers.ToList();
bookinglist.Customers = (from c in db.Customers select c).ToList();
bookinglist.CustomerBookings = (from cb in db.CustomerBookings select cb).ToList();
bookinglist.Coops = (from co in db.Coops select co).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well here is one

```
db.Customers.Where(x=> db.CustomerBookings.Any(a=> a.coopID != x.Id && 
((a.StartDate <= startDate && a.EndDate >= enddate)
|| 
(a.StartDate < endDate && a.EndDate >= enddate)
||
(a.StartDate <= startDate && a.EndDate >= endDate)
)));
```

Comment: Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The other answer looks better but here is a slightly longer solution that is hopefully a bit easier to understand.

```
  //Returns IDs
       var bookingIds = tbl_bookings
             .Where(b => b.ReleaseDate <= startDate && b.ReleaseDate >= endDate
                 || (b.ReleaseDate < endDate && b.ReleaseDate >= endDate)
                 || (b.ReleaseDate <= startDate && b.ReleaseDate >= endDate))
             .Select(b => b.Id);

  //Returns anonymous object list containing all records
  //with an ID not found in previous result set
       var bookings = tbl_bookings.Where(b => !bookingIds.Contains(b.Id))
             .Select(b => new { ID = b.Id, CoopName = b.Id, coopCPN = b.Id })
             .ToList();
```

Comment: Much appreciated